Using semaphores to print out a specific pattern
Given these methods:
void* thread1Func(void* p) {
    while(1) {
        printf("A ");
    }
}

void* thread2Func(void* p) {
    while(1) {
        printf("B ");
    }
}

void* thread3Func(void* p) {
    while(1) {
        printf("C ");
    }
}

Assuming thread1 runs thread1Func, same for thread2 and 3,
We're required to only add semaphores/semaphore methods/thread methods(creation, execution) such that the printed pattern will be A A B C A A B C A A B C A A B C ...
I've got code printing out the correct pattern, with no errors:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t semaphoreA, semaphoreB, semaphoreC;

void* thread1Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreA);  // Wait for semaphoreA
        printf("A ");
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the second 'A'
        sem_wait(&semaphoreA);  // Wait for semaphoreA again
        printf("A ");
        sem_post(&semaphoreB);  // Signal semaphoreB for 'B'
    }
}

void* thread2Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);  // Wait for semaphoreB
        printf("B ");
        sem_post(&semaphoreC);  // Signal semaphoreC for 'C'
    }
}

void* thread3Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreC);  // Wait for semaphoreC
        printf("C ");
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3;

    // Initialize semaphores
    sem_init(&semaphoreA, 0, 1);  // semaphoreA starts unlocked
    sem_init(&semaphoreB, 0, 0);  // semaphoreB starts locked
    sem_init(&semaphoreC, 0, 0);  // semaphoreC starts locked

    // Create threads
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread1Func, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread2Func, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, thread3Func, NULL);

    // Wait for threads to finish (which they won't in this case due to while(1))
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread3, NULL);

    // Destroy semaphores
    sem_destroy(&semaphoreA);
    sem_destroy(&semaphoreB);
    sem_destroy(&semaphoreC);

    return 0;
}

However this solution involves adding another print statement, which is not allowed.
I've tried different approachs to incrementing/decrementing the semaphores yet all either fail/ print the pattern
A B C A B C A B C A B C ...

I've played around with the wait/post methods, and also with the semaphore initial value, I've got this code that got me the correct pattern, however I am unsure on why this is working:
(added just the parts where I've changed values)
sem_t semaphoreA, semaphoreB, semaphoreC;

void* thread1Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreA);  // Wait for semaphoreA
        printf("A ");           // Print 'A'
        sem_post(&semaphoreB);  // Signal semaphoreB for 'B'
        sem_post(&semaphoreC);  // Signal semaphoreC for 'C'
    }
}

void* thread2Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);  // Wait for semaphoreB
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);
        printf("B ");           // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
    }
}

void* thread3Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreC);  // Wait for semaphoreC
        sem_wait(&semaphoreC);  
        printf("C ");          // Print 'C' and newline
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Initialize semaphores
    sem_init(&semaphoreA, 0, 2);  // semaphoreA starts unlocked
    sem_init(&semaphoreB, 0, -1);  // semaphoreB starts locked
    sem_init(&semaphoreC, 0, -1);  // semaphoreC starts locked

    // ...
}


What is your question? Why is it working? It does not work. I see how that could work by luck, but B and C could also be switched.

As a hint, because you got it almost: After 2 A, there should be 1 B. After 1 B there should be 1 C. After 1 C there should be 2 A, etc. Your implementation is: After 2 A there should be B and C (which could be CB too) ...

You're overthinking the problem.  First, think about what has to happen at each logical step.

Print 2 As
Print 1 B
Print 1 C

Your A thread only cares about its turn and unblocking B, so start there.
void* thread1Func(void* p) {                                                    
    while (1) {                                                                 
        sem_wait(&semaphoreA);  // Wait for semaphoreA                          
        printf("A ");                                                           
        sem_post(&semaphoreB);  // Signal semaphoreB for 'B'                    
    }                                                                           
}

Now to make B work, it needs to wait twice, since we always need two As.
void* thread2Func(void* p) {                                                    
    while (1) {                                                                 
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);  // Wait for semaphoreB                          
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);  // Wait for semaphoreB                          
        printf("B ");                                                           
        sem_post(&semaphoreC);  // Signal semaphoreC for 'C'                    
    }                                                                           
}

Lastly, C needs to signal A twice since we want two prints.
void* thread3Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreC);  // Wait for semaphoreC
        printf("C ");
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
    }
}

The only other thing you need to change is the initial value of semaphoreA to 2 (sem_init(&semaphoreA, 0, 2)) so that its loop will execute twice.

Just the answer i needed
what would you think is a correct approach of thinking when working with semaphores? I've understood how mutex locks work pretty nicely (they're simple compared to semaphores, thats how i see it)

I guess something like this would work :
 void* thread1Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreA);  // Wait for semaphoreA
        printf("A ");           // Print 'A'
        sem_post(&semaphoreB);  // Signal semaphoreB for 'B'
    }
}

void* thread2Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);  // Wait for semaphoreB
        sem_wait(&semaphoreB);
        printf("B ");           // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
        sem_post(&semaphoreC);  // Signal semaphoreC for 'C'
    }
}

void* thread3Func(void* p) {
    while (1) {
        sem_wait(&semaphoreC);  // Wait for semaphoreC
        printf("C ");          // Print 'C' and newline
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
        sem_post(&semaphoreA);  // Signal semaphoreA for the next 'A'
    }
}


same problem, it could be A A B C or A A C B. And you did semaphoreA wrong, so it could be A A A A A A A A A .....

I see what you mean, I guess now it's better
